# UnknownHostException accessing service on virtualBox

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Oracle NoSQL is a database that should be hosted on Linux, so I have a virtual Ubuntu running in Oracle VM VirtualBox.

When you run the KvStore for Oracle NoSQL it uses port 5000 for the database, and 5001 for the admin console. From my pc, I can access the admin console running on the linux virtual machine like so:

```
http://192.168.0.25:5001/
```

Where 192.168.0.25 is the inet addr I get from the linux machine's ifconfig command.

However, if I try to connect to the database from java, passing java the host and port number like so:

```
KVStoreConfig kvconfig = new KVStoreConfig("kvstore", "192.168.0.25:5000");
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" oracle.kv.FaultException: Could not contact any RepNode at: [192.168.0.25:5000] (11.2.2.0.26)
Fault class name: oracle.kv.KVStoreException
    at oracle.kv.KVStoreFactory.getStore(KVStoreFactory.java:123)
    at nosql.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: oracle.kv.KVStoreException: Could not contact any RepNode at: [192.168.0.25:5000]
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.TopologyLocator.getInitialTopology(TopologyLocator.java:226)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.TopologyLocator.get(TopologyLocator.java:85)
    at oracle.kv.impl.api.RequestDispatcherImpl.<init>(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:285)
    at oracle.kv.KVStoreFactory.getStore(KVStoreFactory.java:118)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: coraythan-VirtualBox; nested exception is: 
    java.net.UnknownHostException: coraythan-VirtualBox
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:616)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getSerialVersion(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.registry.RemoteAPI.<init>(RemoteAPI.java:60)
    at oracle.kv.impl.rep.admin.RepNodeAdminAPI.<init>(RepNodeAdminAPI.java:63)
    at oracle.kv.impl.rep.admin.RepNodeAdminAPI.wrap(RepNodeAdminAPI.java:70)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.TopologyLocator.getInitialTopology(TopologyLocator.java:191)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: coraythan-VirtualBox
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at oracle.kv.impl.util.registry.ClientSocketFactory.createSocket(ClientSocketFactory.java:300)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 14 more
```

I can get that to work fine when I host a KvStore on my normal computer and try to connect to it like that (using the normal computer's IP address) with java.

Another weird thing is that if I'm in the virtual machine, I can access the admin with this:

```
coraythan-virtualbox:5001
```

But if I try to do that from my main computer it gives me a "could not find" error.

I have tried changing my java connection to coraythan-virtualbox:5000, but that also doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you even ping from your host to 192.168.0.25 ? Which type of network adapter have you configured for the vm box? host-only or bridged?

Comment: bridged, and yes I can ping it.

Comment: Have a look at this question it seems like you have problems reaching the port http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port using the nmap command you should be able to actually see if the port is reachable from your host.

Comment: @Stainedart Well, I just tried using nmap from the virtual machine and main machine, and both seem to say that port is open and ready. In the main machine it said: `Host is up (0.0010s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE

5000/tcp filtered upnp`

Comment: See https://github.com/enexusde/vboxjws/wiki/Code-Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the linux computer did not automatically register its network name with my company's network. I had to have the network admin manually add a network name for the computer. The KVStore requires using the network name it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a socket using named address, that is DNS doesn't know such name. Try change it to IP address.

[UnknownHostException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be
>   determined.

Comment: @Stainedart That's what I said, use IP instead of hostname.

Comment: I am trying to connect using "192.168.0.25:5000". That's what it won't connect with.

Comment: I'm also wandering how OP will pass through NAT.